# How to escape special symbols inside org mode links

Tags: emacs, escaping, org-mode

org-mode has the following format for links:

```
[[<file-name>::<text-to-search>][<link text>]]
```

What should I do, if `<text-to-search>` contains ']' symbol? Like this:

```
$form['input']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special symbols must be URL-encoded: instead of `[` we should write `%5B` and `]` -> `%5D`:

```
[[<file-name>::$form%5B%27input%27%5D][<link text>]]
```